# Showing Lebesgue integral over set of measure zero is in fact zero zero.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> **Question:** Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue measurable set for which $\operatorname{m}(E)=0$, where $\operatorname{m}$ denotes the Lebesgue measure. I'm trying to show that this implies
> $$\int_{E}e^{-x^2/2}dx=0.\tag{1}$$

(Attempted) **Solution:** Let $f:=e^{-x^2/2}$. Since $0 < f \leq 1$ over $\mathbb{R}$, and thus over any $E\subset\mathbb{R}$, it follows

$$0\leq\int_{E}e^{-x^2/2}dx\leq\int_{E}1dx = 1\cdot\operatorname{m}(E) =0.$$

That is,

$$0\leq\int_{E}e^{-x^2/2}dx\leq0.$$

Therefore, indeed we have that $(1)$ holds.

---

My question is, is this solution correct? If not, can it be *repaired*? And if not, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: @RobArthan: Thanks for the conformation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works. Your argument shows that if $f$ is bounded on a set $E$ of Lebesgue measure zero, then $\int_E f = 0$. In fact the stronger claim that $\int_E f = 0$ without any hypothesis on $f$ holds! Indeed the integral is, by definition, the supremum over $g$ with $g$ simple and $g \leq f$ of $\int_E g$. But any such $g$ has integral zero.